# Django Serializers - Datetime with multiple possible formats

Tags: django, date, datetime, format, django-serializer

I want my Django Serializer to validate the format of a date according to several possible formats. Essentially, these formats are:

- just the date (YYYY-MM-DD)
- date + hours  (YYYY-MM-DD HH)
- date + hours + minutes  (YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM)
- date + hours + minutes + seconds  (YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS)

I know that the final two are possible together, using the `DateTimeField` with `format= '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S`.

I know the first one is possible by default using the `DateField`.

I assume the second one is possible using the `DateTimeField` with `format= '%Y-%m-%d %H'`, but I haven't tested.

What I want to know is: is there a **straightforward** way to combine all these validators together, without having to use custom functions/validators? For example, my first instinct was to provide a list of possible formats to the `format` parameter on the `Date/DateTime` fields, but with no success. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: You want to specify the `input_formats` argument?...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my answer from [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70744495/django-serializers-datetime-with-multiple-possible-formats/70745100#comment125065023_70744495) by [Abdul Aziz Barkat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14991864/abdul-aziz-barkat):

> You want to specify the `input_formats` argument?...

Comment: Was that the answer? Can you explain a little more if it was?